# Finding $\omega$ with an arithmetic series

Tags: arithmetic, infinity, ordinals

I just watched a really interesting video by Vsauce about counting past infinity [**here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrU9YDoXE88), and from which I have now learned that the next number after infinity, is $\omega$, then $\omega+1$, and so on.

From another video I have seen, showing how [**every positive number adds to -1/12**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-I6XTVZXww), allow me to pose a question:

If every (positive) number added together equals -1/12, then we can determine the equation is:

$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i=-\frac{1}{12}$

From the first video, we know that $\omega$ is equal to $\infty+1$, so by that logic, would the following equation be correct?

$\sum_{i=0}^{\omega}i=\frac{11}{12}$

Comment: How did you get 11/12? Shouldn’t it be $\omega-11/12$?

Comment: @ziggurism Uhhh, -1/12 + 1 = 11/12

Comment: So is your sum $1+2+3+\dotsb + \omega$ or is it $1+2+3+\dotsb + 1$? You wrote the former in your question but now you’re saying it’s the latter? Are you adding a 1 or an omega?

Comment: The moral of this story is don't just take the things you see on youtube for granted. Try to find some more legitimate readable sources relating to the topics you're interested in to see if those claims hold up.

Comment: @ziggurism The former, however I really don't know personally, I only looked at the video and made an assumption. I don't know enough about these equations to make a real educated response, I only did really basic AP's recently.

Comment: @cws Oh ofcourse, just a little thing I had on my mind. :)

Comment: @finnrayment If you start with $1+2+3+\dotsb = -1/12$ and add $\omega$ to both sides, you don't get $1-1/12$ you get $\omega-1/12$. Of course that doesn't mean $\omega-1/12$ is the answer. I don't know of any definition of transfinite sum that would result in that answer...

Comment: @ziggurism OHHHHH, right. Sorry, I get it now.

Answer (score 5):

You are making a huge mess.

1. $\omega$ is not a *number* according to the common conception, it is an ordinal. The arithmetics of [ordinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) is pretty different from the arithmetics over $\mathbb{Z}$: for instance, $1+\omega\neq \omega+1$. Additionally, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a set while $\mathbb{ON}$ is a proper class by the Burali-Forti paradox;
2. The series $\sum_{n\geq 1}n$ is simply divergent. Of course, for any $s>1$ we have 
   $$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s}$$
   and the Riemann $\zeta$ function has an analytic continuation to the complex plane, allowing to state $\zeta(-1)=-\frac{1}{12}$, but this is pretty different from stating that $\sum_{n\geq 1}n = -\frac{1}{12}$;
3. By 1. and 2., $\sum_{n=1}^{\omega}n$ is *doubly meaningless*.

Comment: Woaaaaa, this is way over my head. I'll go look up these things now.